# Can we store javascript code in any one column of mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, adsense

Will there be any problem like cross site scripting if I make a provision for storing an individual's javascript code in a column of a mysql database?

Suppose if twitter has a mysql database, and it allows users to display their own Google Adsense ads in their own profiles by giving them an option to upload their own javascript code  into their database. Is it fatal for a database?

Comment: Database doesn't care what stored in it.

Comment: yeah.thats right.. but I wanted to check how vulnerable my app would become if i allow such a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is a bad idea, as you have no control over what kind of scripts are included.

The better idea i to allow users to insert their Google AdSense identifiers within separate field and tell them you will insert JS snippet for them. Just make sure that identifier contains only chars that are allowed in such identifier, no JS code or HTML tags allowed.

Comment: I happen to use SSL for my site... then I will have to check each and every ads posted by users to see if they are SSL secured too

Comment: @RobbieDc: It is **a lot** more complex issue than just checking for SSL. If you allow for their code being included in your site without restrictions, you are totally vulnerable to XSS, which means they can read your cookies, alter HTML of your site, track your users etc. So, basically as I said: **it is a bad idea**.